# Error when starting Datomic shell: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jline/ConsoleRunner

Tags: java, windows, datomic

I followed the instructions on the Datomic site: http://docs.datomic.com/getting-started.html, but I'm getting this error when trying to start up the datomic shell prompt. I'm using a windows machine. Any suggestions? I tried the same thing on my linux box and did not get this error.

Edit: moved to a different windows machine and it's working. If I have time to troubleshoot this problem and I find a solution I'll report back

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` usually mean your class path is somehow broken.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that you cannot run the shell.cmd from within the bin directory, you need to call it with bin\shell.cmd from the parent directory... hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using `cygwin/bash` and call `bin/shell` : 
The java runtime on windows does not understand classpath with a **":"**
but this is what you get from `bin/classpath`.
Either correct this or use DOS-CMD shell and call bin/shell.cmd inside.

Regards

Comment: In this case I was using the cmd shell

Answer (score 1):

Some tips for running datomic on Windows (7 at least):

Do not download datomic into Program Files. On startup, it creates logging directories and temp files into its own directories, so unless you run the command prompt as Administrator, you're gonna have screens full of *Unable to write to file...* errors.

You need to run datomic as such (assuming you extracted the download to C:)

```
c:\datomic-free-0.x.xxxx>bin\shell.cmd
```

Note the backslash. Tripped me up forever coming from *nix world.

After that, return to your regularly scheduled datomic tutorials.